# Rotate one column and Select it comma seperated

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
PK | COL1 | COL2
----------------
1  |  A   |  a
2  |  B   |  b
3  |  C   |  c
4  |  A   |  d
5  |  A   |  e
6  |  B   |  f
7  |  C   |  g
8  |  C   |  h
```

and I want to do an Select that I get the following result

```
COL1 | COL2
---------------
 A   | a,d,e
 B   | b,f
 C   | c,g,h
```

As I understand SQL at the moment I don't know how to do this without "programing" something extra e.q. with PL/SQL 
But i search for an DBMS independent solution as good as it can be DBMS independent.

Comment: You should always specfy which DBMS you are using. I added the `oracle` tag for you as you mentioned PL/SQL

Answer (score 2):

This is an Oracle (11.2) solution:

```
select col1, 
       listagg(col2, ',') within group (order by col1) as col2
from the_table
group by col1;
```

As you need this for other DBMS as well, this would be the Postgres solution:

```
select col1, 
       string_agg(col2, ',' order by col1) as col2
from the_table
group by col1;
```

For MySQL this would be:

```
select col1, 
       group_concat(col2 ORDER BY col1 SEPARATOR ',') as col2
from the_table
group by col1;
```

For a SQL Server solution, see Vijaykumar's answer.

Comment: I do not mandatory use a Oracle DB. Should work with every SQL-DBMS

Comment: @TomStadler: there is no solution that works on all DBMS (there is no standard defined for aggregating character columns)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution works very good for me. I didn't know before about these functions. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this !!

```
SELECT  [col1], 
            SUBSTRING(d.col2,1, LEN(d.col2) - 1) col2
    FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT [col1]
                FROM table1
            ) a
            CROSS APPLY
            (
                SELECT [col2] + ', ' 
                FROM table1 AS b 
                WHERE a.[col1] = b.[col1]
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) d (col2)
```

Comment: WHERE A.[col1] = B.[col1]
you mean the "a" from the first subselect?

Comment: yes,it was a typo i edited  @TomStadler

Comment: Thank you for your effort! works ;-)